# Insert Missing Days & Copy Earlier Day data to missing days

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a table Summary, with the following columns -
Date
Bank Name
MtM
RW 3%
Options
CCS
CCS 6%
Below is sample table -

| Date | Bank Name | MtM | RW 3% | Options | CCS | CCS 6% |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 29 Dec 2023 | Citibank | 300 | 45 | 0 | 375 | 0 |
| 30 Dec 2023 | HSBC | 175 | 225 | 0 | 0 | 200 |
| 02 Jan 2023 | Citibank | 475 | 150 | 28 | 0 | 220 |

I would like to copy the data of 30th Dec, 2023 for 31st December 2023 and 1st Jan 2024 with the same values as of 30th Dec 2023.

How can i do this in Power BI.

Appreciate any help !

Tried to manually load the file and then append, but its messing up the table structure.

Comment: On your current data you only have 1 row per day?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**PowerQuery**

Try the following steps in PowerQuery for your table/query.

```
let
  Source = YOUR_SOURCE,
  #"Changed column type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source, {{"Date", type date}}),
  #"Sorted rows" = Table.Sort(#"Changed column type", {{"Date", Order.Ascending}}),
  #"Added index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(#"Sorted rows", "Index", 0, 1, Int64.Type),
  #"Added custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added index", "Custom", each 
  let
    thisDate = [Date],
    nextDate = try Date.AddDays(#"Added index"{[Index] +1}[Date], -1) otherwise [Date],
    listDate = { Number.From(thisDate)..Number.From(nextDate) }
  in
    listDate
  ),
  #"Expanded Custom" = Table.ExpandListColumn(#"Added custom", "Custom"),
  #"Changed column type 1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Expanded Custom", {{"Custom", type date}}),
  #"Removed columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Changed column type 1", {"Date", "Index"}),
  #"Renamed columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Removed columns", {{"Custom", "Date"}})
in
  #"Renamed columns"
```

---

**DAX**

```
NewTable = 
  var dates = 
    SELECTCOLUMNS(
      CALENDAR( MIN('YourTable'[Date]), MAX('YourTable'[Date])),
      "DateNew", [Date]
    )
  var missingDate = EXCEPT(dates, DISTINCT('YourTable'[Date]))
  var missingRows = GENERATE(missingDate, TOPN(1, FILTER('YourTable', [Date] < [DateNew]), [Date], DESC))

  return UNION(
    'YourTable',
    SELECTCOLUMNS(
      missingRows,
      "Date", [DateNew],
      "Bank Name", [Bank Name],
      "MtM", [MtM],
      "RW 3%", [RW 3%],
      "Options", [Options],
      "CCS", [CCS],
      "CCS 6%", [CCS 6%]
    )
  )
```

Comment: Great use of `GENERATE`! Amazing as always, Sam!

Answer (score 0):

You can join your data with a table with dates, you can generate one with List.Dates for example. And with a Left join have the Empty dates. After that you can Fill Down the dates. There are other approaches.

You can review the implementation by using the following Power Query M in a Blank Query.

```
let
    Source = List.Dates(#date(2023,12,1),60,#duration(1,0,0,0)),
    Source2 = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("i45WMjIwMtY1NNI1slTSUXLOLMlMSszLBjKNDQyApIkpkAAxjM0hrFgdhBZjkIRHsJMzkDIEyxsZwdSDsJEBXL2JroGhroERqhUmYD2GpmC1FjBNRkBNsQA=", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [Date = _t, #"Bank Name" = _t, MtM = _t, #"RW 3%" = _t, Options = _t, CCS = _t, #"CCS 6%" = _t]),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source2,{{"Date", type date}, {"Bank Name", type text}, {"MtM", Int64.Type}, {"RW 3%", Int64.Type}, {"Options", Int64.Type}, {"CCS", Int64.Type}, {"CCS 6%", Int64.Type}}),

    #"Converted to Table" = Table.FromList(Source, Splitter.SplitByNothing(),{"Dates"} , null, ExtraValues.Error),
    #"Merged Queries" = Table.NestedJoin(#"Converted to Table", {"Dates"}, Table, {"Date"}, "Table", JoinKind.LeftOuter),
    #"Expanded Table" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Merged Queries", "Table", {"Bank Name", "MtM", "RW 3%", "Options", "CCS", "CCS 6%"}, {"Bank Name", "MtM", "RW 3%", "Options", "CCS", "CCS 6%"}),
    #"Filled Down" = Table.FillDown(#"Expanded Table",{"Bank Name", "MtM", "RW 3%", "Options", "CCS", "CCS 6%"}),
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Filled Down", each ([Bank Name] <> null))
in
    #"Filtered Rows"
```